# Name for shape defined by volume between two concentric spheres

Tags: terminology, geometry

Is there a proper name for a shape defined by the volume between two concentric spheres? My understanding is that, formally, a "sphere" is strictly a 2D surface and there's a formal term for volume contained by that surface -- which I forget.

Is there a term that describes the volume between two concentric spheres? That is, colloquially, a "a filled in sphere with a hollow core".

Another phrasing would be, what is the name for a three dimensional annulus? (Or is an annulus not strictly two dimensional?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a "[spherical shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_shell)".

Answer (score 0):

It's also called an [annulus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnnulusTheorem.html). ${}$